# Write a script to extract a date string from a text file and replace it with a date for 7 days after in Windows

Tags: scripting, winrar

We have a text file which is telling [WinRAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinRAR) to zip all of the files after the mentioned date:

```
"C:\Program Files\winrar\Rar.exe" a -r -m0 -ta20140501 zip.rar e:\test\*
```

(`-ta<date>`: *Process files modified after the specified date*)

I want a script to extract the date information from `-ta20140501` and replace it with a date 7 days later. That is, it will be 20140508.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script which can be executed with text editor [UltraEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit) to modify the date string in the text file.

```js
if (UltraEdit.document.length > 0)  // Is any file opened?
{
   // Define environment for this script.
   UltraEdit.insertMode();
   UltraEdit.columnModeOff();

   // Define the parameters for a case-sensitive (faster) Perl
   // regular expression find in current file from top to bottom.
   UltraEdit.perlReOn();
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.mode=0;
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.matchCase=true;
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.matchWord=false;
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.regExp=true;
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.searchDown=true;
   if (typeof(UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.searchInColumn) == "boolean")
   {
      UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.searchInColumn=false;
   }
   // Move caret to top of the active file.
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.top();

   // Is a date string in format YYYYMMDD after switch -ta found?
   if(UltraEdit.activeDocument.findReplace.find("(?<=-ta)\\d{8}"))
   {
      // Get this date string from the current text file.
      var sDate = UltraEdit.activeDocument.selection;
      // Get year, month and day of month as integer numbers.
      var nYear = parseInt(sDate.substr(0,4),10);
      var nMonth = parseInt(sDate.substr(4,2),10);
      var nDay = parseInt(sDate.substr(6,2),10);
      // Get number of milliseconds since epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT).
      var nMsecEpoch = Date.UTC(nYear,nMonth-1,nDay,0,0,0);
      // Create a new date object with a time 7 days after found date.
      var oNewDate = new Date();
      oNewDate.setTime(7*86400*1000+nMsecEpoch);
      // Get year, month and day of month for this new date
      // and convert it to a date string in format YYYYMMDD.
      var sNewDate = oNewDate.getUTCFullYear().toString(10);
      nMonth = oNewDate.getUTCMonth()+1;
      if (nMonth < 10) sNewDate += "0";
      sNewDate += nMonth.toString(10);
      nDay = oNewDate.getUTCDate();
      if (nDay < 10) sNewDate += "0";
      sNewDate += nDay.toString(10);
      // Write new string to file replacing still selected date string.
      UltraEdit.activeDocument.write(sNewDate);
      // Close the file with saving it.
      UltraEdit.closeFile(UltraEdit.activeDocument.path,1);
   }
}
```

UltraEdit uses the JavaScript core engine as the scripting engine. The JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, with its methods, is used in this UltraEdit script to add 7 days to date string found in the text file.

This scripting code needs to be copied into a new ASCII file saved, for example, to folder `%APPDATA%\IDMComp\UltraEdit\Scripts` with name `UpdateDateString.js`.

The following command can be used in a batch file to run UltraEdit with the file to modify and this script to modify the date string in the text file.

```
@start "Update Date" /wait /min "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IDMComp\UltraEdit\uedit32.exe" /fni "Path to\Command Text File\WinRAR_Command_File.txt" /s,e="%APPDATA%\IDMComp\UltraEdit\Scripts\UpdateDateString.js"
```

`"Path to\Command Text File\WinRAR_Command_File.txt"` is the name of the text file to modify with complete path.

`/fni` must be the first parameter for `uedit32.exe` and specifies to force a new instance of UltraEdit for loading the text file and modifying it with the script. This is an important parameter supported since version 13.10 of UltraEdit for Windows in case of an UltraEdit instance is already running and the configuration setting *Allow multiple instances* is not enabled in configuration of UltraEdit.

`/s,e="..."` is the parameter to instruct UltraEdit to load the script file specified within the double quotes, run it on the file loaded, and exit after script finished.

As UltraEdit is a Windows GUI application, it is necessary to use command `start` to run UltraEdit with a minimized window and halt execution of the batch file until UltraEdit terminates itself.

But honestly, I think, it would make more sense and is definitely much easier, to use the WinRAR command line switch `-tn7d` instead of `-taYYYYMMDD` to archive all files modified in the last 7 days measured from current time.